# Событийно ориентированное и асинхронное программирование

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

В чем разница между событийно ориентированным и асинхронным программированием? Если можно, на каком нибудь контрастном примере.

Comment: Java Stream ни к тому ни к другому отношения не имеет.

Comment: Поторопился. Исправил